# Inconsistent shellshock exploitation

Tags: bash, shellshock, vulnerability

I am trying to demonstrate the shellshock vulnerability according to the commands posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/631257/how-to-test-if-my-server-is-vulnerable-to-the-shellshock-bug).

I have taken two systems under consideration: the first one has a vulnerable bash in `$PATH`; the other has a patched version of bash in `$PATH`, and a "supposedly vulnerable" version in `/opt/vulnerable`, that has been compiled from source.

On the **first system**, I am able to successfully exploit the bug:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
[...]

$ cat << EOM | bash
> env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
> EOM
vulnerable
this is a test
```

On the **second system**, as described above, there is a patched bash in `$PATH` and a recently (as in a few hours ago) compiled from source version of `bash` in `/opt/vulnerable` that should be vulnerable:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
[...]

$ /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash
GNU bash, version 4.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
[...]
```

I'm passing these commands through the default version to the vulnerable version, and I'm unable to exploit it:

```
$ cat << EOM | /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash
> env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
> EOM
this is a test
```

I've also tried using [this](https://github.com/wreiske/shellshocker/blob/master/shellshock_test.sh) script for testing, but it fails to detect any vulnerability. (The command has been issued from the default, patched shell):

```
$ /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash shellshock_test.sh
CVE-2014-6271 (original shellshock): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-6277 (segfault): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-6278 (Florian's patch): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-7169 (taviso bug): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-7186 (redir_stack bug): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-7187 (nested loops off by one): not vulnerable
CVE-2014-//// (exploit 3 on http://shellshocker.net/): not vulnerable
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or have all bash sources archives on ftp.gnu.org have been patched against this vulnerability?

Comment: Isn't the second line running `bash` from `$PATH` instead of `/opt/vulnerable`?

Comment: @Mikel, are you talking about the "second line" from the first code block? That's just some information taken from a system with a vulnerable `bash` in `$PATH` to confirm that versions <= 4.1.2 have this vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat << EOM | /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash
> env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
> EOM
```

Is wrong.

On the 2nd line, you're calling `bash`, which will use the version in `$PATH` <sup>1</sup>.

You want to use the version of `bash` in `/opt/vulnerable/bin/bash`, like this:

```
$ cat << EOM | /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash
> env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash -c "echo this is a test"
> EOM
```

Tho I can't see any need for you to call bash twice and use a pipe like that.  Why not just:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo this is a test'
```

and

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' /opt/vulnerable/bin/bash -c 'echo this is a test'
```

I verified using `bash` versus `~/src/bash/bash` on my system:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
4.3.11(1)-release

$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' ~/src/bash/bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
4.3.42(1)-release
```

---

Footnotes:

1. Or a function, an alias, the version in `hash`, etc.